# Django Social Auth error: "Missing required parameter: client_id" while trying to authenticate with Google Outh2

Tags: django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I have installed and configured `social-auth-app-django` and added an option to sign up with google in my login page. But whenever I click the link, I get this error [image: error]

Comment: Did you define `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY` and `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET`?

Comment: `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = ''` 
Yes, I included this in my settings.py

Comment: Included like that? Without values?

Comment: Is it the right way? Or I was supposed to put something between these apostrophies?

Comment: Yes, what values are required here?

Comment: You need to fill them with the `Client ID` and `Client Secret` generated when you register the app with Google. Check the docs here http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/google.html#google-oauth2

Comment: I am deeply thankful that you helped me for the second time :)

Answer (score 0):

In the redirected uri option-
copy paste the uri given i.e. uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/google-oauth2/